# Have SvelteKit project being all prerendered with [slug]s in routing

Tags: vite, sveltekit, prerender

I have a SvelteKit/Tauri project which all needs to be prerendered as it will be a desktop application. In my SvelteKit project, i have the following routing, which contains a slug:

```
/edit/calculator/[calculator_id]
```

The slug parameter is an `id` used to querying the calculator with the given `id` and then display the calculators properties. I do not know the `calculator_id` parameters in my embedded database beforehand, which makes the routes unknown at compile/build time.

When building the project, i get the following error:

```
node:internal/event_target:1033
  process.nextTick(() => { throw err; });
                           ^
Error: The following routes were marked as prerenderable, but were not prerendered because they were not found while crawling your app:
  - /edit/calculator/[calculator_id]

See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#prerender-troubleshooting for info on how to solve this
    at prerender (file:///C:/Users/ono/Documents/Programmering/versa-flow/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/core/postbuild/prerender.js:475:9)
    at async MessagePort.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/ono/Documents/Programmering/versa-flow/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/utils/fork.js:22:16)
Emitted 'error' event on Worker instance at:
    at [kOnErrorMessage] (node:internal/worker:300:10)
    at [kOnMessage] (node:internal/worker:311:37)
    at MessagePort.<anonymous> (node:internal/worker:212:57)
    at [nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:757:20)
    at exports.emitMessage (node:internal/per_context/messageport:23:28)
```

I have tried to look into the [documentation mentioned in the error message](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#prerender-troubleshooting), it talks about specifying specific pages as prerenderable, but i do not understand it properly and know how to fix this issue by reading the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation states that dynamic parameters can be pre-rendered only if there are links to said route with specific parameter values.  You cannot pre-render a dynamic route if the parameter values are not known.

In other words, you cannot possibly pre-render all possible combinations of URL's that are possible.  You can list explicit cases in the `entries` option as stated in the document, or forget about pre-rendering.

Summarizing:  You cannot pre-render without first assigning values to the route parameters.

Comment: That is also what the internet seems to say, without explicitly saying it as you have done so nicely here. Thank you!